# Display characters other than alphabets using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to have this functionality in the server side using `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

```
"cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678".match(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g).join('');
```

Comment: `.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]+", "")`?

Comment: So you want to ignore non-English letters as well?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve, some examples of inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: @peter yes.but it should allow white spaces

Comment: @Duncan i should get the result as #254778678

Comment: @prakash I suspect that ignoring all letters (including non-English alphabets) will be challenging to define as a pattern. It might be easier to define what you *do* want in the output, e.g. numbers and symbols. Do you think you can describe the allowed character set in your output?

Comment: Can you define "alphabets"?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `Pattern` just simple `replaceAll` will do the trick,

```
String s=  "cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678".replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: i want to display the characters other than alphabets... result should be like this #254778678